# Local minimums of a functional in an interval

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, maxima-minima, functional-calculus

Consider the below functional

$F=\int_0^L dx [d_x f(x)]^2,$

with boundary conditions

$\cos 2 f(0)=\cos 2 f(L),$

$\sin 2 f(0)=\sin 2 f(L)$.

Are the set of functions $f(x)=\frac{n \pi x}{L}$ (with integer $n$), local minimums of $F$? Is there any way to show that these are local minimums? Obviously, the case $n=0$ is the global minimum.

Comment: By "$d_x f(x)$", do you mean derivative of $f(x)$? Does "$[.]$" simply denote brackets, or is it supposed to mean floor function or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ G ( u , v , w ) = w ^ 2 $. Then $ F [ f ] = \int _ 0 ^ L G \big( x , f ( x ) , f ' ( x ) \big) \ \mathrm d x $. The local minimizers of $ F $ must satisfy the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation):
$$ \frac { \partial G } { \partial v } \big( x , f ( x ) , f ' ( x ) \big) - \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d x } \left( \frac { \partial G } { \partial w } \big( x , f ( x ) , f ' ( x ) \big) \right) = 0 $$
That simply shows $ f '' ( x ) = 0 $, and hence there are constants $ a $ and $ b $ such that $ f ( x ) = a x + b $. The boundary conditions are equivalent to existence of an integer $ n $ with $ 2 f ( L ) = 2 f ( 0 ) + 2 n \pi $. Thus we have $ a L + b = b + n \pi $, which shows that $ a = \frac { n \pi } L $. Therefore local minimizers are of the form $ f ( x ) = \frac { n \pi } L x + b $.

To show that each of those functions are actually local minimizers, it's [sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Variations_and_sufficient_condition_for_a_minimum) to prove that the second variation of $ F $ is strictly positive.

$$ F [ f + \epsilon \eta ] = \int _ 0 ^ L G \big( x , f ( x ) + \epsilon \eta ( x ) , f ' ( x ) + \epsilon \eta ' ( x ) \big) \ \mathrm d x = \\
\int _ 0 ^ L f ' ( x ) ^ 2 \ \mathrm d x + 2 \epsilon \int _ 0 ^ L f ' ( x ) \eta ' ( x ) \ \mathrm d x + \epsilon ^ 2 \int _ 0 ^ L \eta ' ( x ) ^ 2 \ \mathrm d x $$

$$ \delta ^ 2 F [ f , \eta ] = \left[ \frac { \mathrm d ^ 2 } { \mathrm d \epsilon ^ 2 } F [ f , \eta ] \right] _ { \epsilon = 0 } = \int _ 0 ^ L \eta ' ( x ) ^ 2 \ \mathrm d x = \| \eta ' \| \ge \frac 4 { L ^ 2 } \| \eta \| ^ 2 $$

For a proof of the above inequality, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218695/l2-norm-of-a-function-and-its-derivative) for example.

Comment: Is there any way of finding the height of the barrier between two of the local minimas?

Comment: Do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: @Marco First of all, I don't know what you mean by "the barrier between two of the local minima" and its "height". Second of all, as there has been [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755795/finding-the-barrier-height-between-two-local-minimums-of-free-energy) asking for the same, with the same notation and terminology, I suspect this is a homework question, and the other account is either another one of yours, or belonging to someone assigned with the same question. This site is not for doing others' homework.

Comment: It is not a homework question. The other account is mine, I used my mobile to end that question and it used another email address of mine! I hadn't realized this till now! the barrier is the vale of F which is needed to go from one minimum to another. I have added a figure to that question.

Comment: Well, in that case, don't you think it's very easy to calculate the barrier? You know the form of the minima, you can calculate $F$ at the minima, and you can take the difference. Why asking another question for that?!

Comment: Oh, no! the barrier is not the difference between two minimas. It is more difficult and I am not even sure if it's possible to find it. I have added a clarifying figure to that question.