# Finding the barrier height between two local minimums of free energy

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, functional-calculus

Consider the below functional

$F=\int_0^L dx [d_x f(x)]^2,$

with boundary conditions

$\cos 2 f(0)=\cos 2 f(L),$

$\sin 2 f(0)=\sin 2 f(L)$.

The set of functions $f(x)=\frac{n \pi x}{L}$ (with integer $n$), are local minimums of $F$. Is it possible to find the height of the barrier between two local minimums say between n= n1 and n=n1+1?

As an example, in the below figure, the barrier height is $\Delta F$. However, in this graph a function is plotted instead of a functional.
[image]